# Typo3 ArgumentCountError Backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Yesterday My Typo3 Backend crashes, I haven't changed anything yet ...

I got the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Middleware\SignalSlotDeprecator::__construct(), 0 passed in /homepages/38/d428634163/htdocs/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 3691 and exactly 1 expected
```

I tried:

- empty cache
- generate new autoload data
- remove all extensions

Any hints for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I Reuploaded the Typo3 Core.